# How to control python program behavior with external file presence/content?

Tags: python, json, external

I developed a software which can be automatically updated, so I need external-placed config file/files. For now I use json file to store user-input variables like user name etc. But I am not sure how the program itself should be controlled. I mean things like checking if program is opened for first time after update to know if update notes should be shown, what functions were already used etc. For now I am doing it with things like:

```
if os.path.exists(control_file_1):
    actions_1
if os.path.exists(control_file_2):
    some other actions unrelated to actions_1
```

it is independent from the files content - so there is no need to read the file content - which is convenient.

What functions should be used to store those information in one file and read them efficiently? Just normal file.read() etc? It seems not very clean-code friendly.

Thanks

UPDATE:
Looks like a ConfigParser is a way to go. Am I right? Or are they any better ways to accomplish what I am going for?

Comment: Honestly, the introduction and then the question: What functions should be used to store those information in one file and read them efficiently? are not much related. What I understood is that you have JSON file that you want to read and then run different functions according to the content of JSON data in the file

Comment: I edited a question - it should be understandable now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you need to have config information stored in a file. If you choose to have that information in a file that contains a json record then it is the most convenient if the file is used internally and updating and reading the record in the file is easy (treat it as a dict)

However, if you want a more universal config.ini reader then you can go with ConfigParser class which you can use directly or create your own wrapper

`class MYConfig_Parser(ConfigParser):`

so that you can check stuff in the constructor like if mandatory entries are available etc before processing the entries.